# Want To vs Wanna

Tags: verbs, contractions

What is the difference between both?

When should I use **Want to** and when should I use **Wanna**?

I was wondering if there is *the correct way* - gramatically speaking - depending on the situation, or if this is just a matter of taste.

Comment: As a general rule, you don't wanna use _wanna_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct and standard version is **want to**.  As a general rule of thumb, always use **want to**.

*Wanna* is an example of [eye dialect](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eye%20dialect), which is writing things in the way to reflect how people actually pronounce them informally, for example

> **An'** then Moses **sez** to Pharaoh...

instead of the standard

> **And** then Moses **says** to Pharaoh...

or

> That was a **helluva** thing to see

instead of

> That was a **hell of a** thing to see

We use eye dialect only when writing extremely informally or when attempting to represent someone's direct speech.

Comment: I wanna expound on your example: *An' then Moses sez to Phay-roh, "Lemmy people go!"*

Comment: So, to be more clearer,  should I use *wanna* when I'm in an informal conversation?

Comment: @FernandoPaz - I wouldn't even use it in an informal conversation.  *Want to* is always going to be correct and understood.  But if you see *wanna* you'll know that you're in a very informal conversation.